Output of ventilator and air friction
Imagine you have a ventilator with straight rectangular ventilator blades which are rotated at some small angle from a perpendicular line to the rotating axis. The ventilator has 100% efficiency (all the electricity given to the ventilator is converted to the spinning motion without any losses). Let the power of the ventilator be e.g. 30W.
What are the parameters that influence the air friction, how much of the power of the ventilator is converted to the heat from the air friction and how much is the kinetic energy of the air?
(estimate information needed or explain generally)
